# Totally wrong result of intval and(int) of double number

Tags: php

I've got this problem on Windows 10 with both php 7 and 7.1 and also on raspbian with PHP 7.0.33
When I try to cast a large double (a miliseconds timestamp) to int I get a totally wrong result. Example:

```
$a = 1512298800000.0;
echo intval($a);
```

The output is: 470311808

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: You are using PHP 32 bit and it's overflowing.

Comment: Try using `echo abs($a);` I am getting this `1512298800000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) Manual, it cleary states:

***Return Values***

The integer value of var on success, or 0 on failure. Empty arrays return 0, non-empty arrays return 1.

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.

Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of integer casting apply.

And

***Notes***

> Note:The base parameter has no effect unless the var parameter is a string.

So basically it seems you are using 32-bit system and value got overflowed from the range of integer.